# Using an AsyncTask to download images into a ListView in an AppWidget

Tags: android, android-appwidget, remoteview

I am trying to adapt the pattern from [Google I/O](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbQb1PVjfqM&feature=youtu.be) using AsyncTask to download images from the network and place them into ListView items within an AppWidget. I haven't found many resources on doing such a thing, except for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380168/update-android-widget-using-async-task-with-an-image-from-the-internet).

The problem is, that poster didn't have a collection view, only a single item. When I try to follow that pattern, the whole appwidget is updated with just the single list item every time the onPostExecute() runs, not what I need. If you remove call to updateAppWidget() in onPostExecute(), the views are not updated, I'm guessing because of the inter-process communication that must occur. I'm not really sure where to go from here, can anyone help?

Here is my definition for the AsyncTask:

```
public ThumbnailAsyncTask(RemoteViews rv, int appWidgetID, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager)
{
    mTarget = rv;
    this.widgetID = appWidgetID;
    this.widgetManager = appWidgetManager;  
}

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params)
{
    String url = params[0];
    return getBitmapFromURL(url);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result)
{
    mTarget.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.thumbnail, result);
    widgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetID, mTarget);
}

private Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String str)
{
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;

    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(str);
        connection = openConnectionWithTimeout(url);
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(connection.getInputStream());
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.disconnect();
    }
    return bmp;
}
}
```

and the getViewAt() from the RemoteViewsFactory:

```
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position)
{
    RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.list_item);
    ArrayList<ResultDetails> mResults = mJSONParser.getResults();

    if (mResults.get(position).hasHeading())
        rv.setTextViewText(R.id.title, mResults.get(position).getHeading());
    if (mResults.get(position).hasBody())
        rv.setTextViewText(R.id.description, mResults.get(position).getBody(true));
    if (mResults.get(position).hasTimestamp())
        rv.setTextViewText(R.id.date, mResults.get(position).getTimestamp(true));

    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString(LINK_ITEM, mResults.get(position).getExternalURL());
    Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
    fillInIntent.putExtras(extras);
    rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.list_item, fillInIntent);

    if (mResults.get(position).hasThumbnailURL())
    {
        AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(mContext);
        new ThumbnailAsyncTask(rv, mAppWidgetId, mgr).execute(mResults.get(position).getThumbnailURL());
    }

    return rv;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't happy with the long load times, so I figured out a way to quickly load a placeholder image, and then load the thumbnails in an AsyncTask, and then call notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged() once to refresh the appwidget after they are all loaded. This results in instant appearance of the data without the images, and is a pretty good solution for my application. I used a boolean value in my RemoteViewsFactory to indicate if I had already downloaded the data with no images, so the it wouldn't get stuck in an endless refresh cycle.

```
class ThumbnailAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
private AppWidgetManager widgetManager;
private List<ResultDetails> details;
private Context context;

public ThumbnailAsyncTask(AppWidgetManager
        appWidgetManager, List<ResultDetails> details, Context context)
{
    this.details = details;
    this.context = context;
    this.widgetManager = appWidgetManager;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
{
    for (ResultDetails item : details)
    {
        if (item.hasThumbnailURL())
        {
            item.setThumbnail(getBitmapFromURL(item.getThumbnailURL()));
        }
    }
    return null;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
{
    widgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(widgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(
                        new ComponentName(context, WidgetProvider.class)), R.id.list_view);

}

public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position)
{
    RemoteViews rv;
    rv = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.list_item);
    ArrayList<ResultDetails> mResults = mSearchResultsGenerator.getResults();
    ResultDetails result = mResults.get(position);

    if (result.hasHeading())
        rv.setTextViewText(R.id.title, result.getHeading());
    if (result.hasBody())
        rv.setTextViewText(R.id.description, result.getBody(true));
    if (result.hasTimestamp())
        rv.setTextViewText(R.id.date, result.getTimestamp(true));
    if (result.hasPrice())
        rv.setTextViewText(R.id.price, result.getPrice());

    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString(LINK_ITEM, result.getExternalURL());
    Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
    fillInIntent.putExtras(extras);
    rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.list_item, fillInIntent);

    if (result.hasThumbnail())
    {
        rv.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.thumbnail, result.getThumbnail());
    }
    else
    {
        rv.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.thumbnail, noImageBitmap);
    }

    return rv;
}
public void onDataSetChanged()
{
    if (isOnline(mContext))
    {
        if (!hasData)
        {
            mSearchResultsGenerator.generate();
            if (mSearchResultsGenerator.isUpdateSucceeded())
            {
                AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(mContext);
                hasData = true;
                new ThumbnailAsyncTask(mgr, mSearchResultsGenerator.getResults(), mContext).execute();
            }
            else
                makeNoConnectionToast();
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    else
        makeNoConnectionToast();
}
```

Comment: This is quite problematic: you save the bitmaps for all items (which can cause OOM in case there are lots of them), and you also create an asyncTask for each item, without cancelling previous ones, so it can cause newly visible items to be loaded much later in case the user is scrolling fast, and even worse: it can cause issues with AsyncTask (crash), as it has a limit of how many of them to create at a given time

Comment: @androiddeveloper You're right, I wrote this when I was just starting with Android. The question remains though, how can this be done better with an App Widget?

Comment: I know. I've searched in a lot of places and didn't find a good solution. What I did now is: restrict number of items to a relatively small number of items and allow to reach the full list on the last item (like on Hangouts) , use a customized thread-pool for the asyncTasks (to avoid the official one and avoid having its issues), map each item-pos to task so that I could cancel previous ones (to avoid multiple tasks working on same item), I used caching to store the bitmaps, and in the end of each asyncTask, I used notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged which will use the filled cache.

Comment: Only when the asyncTask has finished with a good bitmap, I assume the bitmap got into the cache, so I can call the notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged to make it usable. This means that I control the number of threads, and the number of tasks (which is no more than the number of items). I thought I would also need to use a stack-based collection for the tasks (so that what's shown would be loaded first), but it seems that the framework does it anyway, which is a bit weird.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to call [`AppWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged%28int,%20int%29) to refresh collection views in an AppWidget

Comment: put in the onPostExecute(), that just sets an infinite loop of refreshing

Comment: Well, you need to call that to refresh your list, so somewhere you need a different strategy. Not sure what to tell you, unfortunately. Maybe your AppWidgetProvider can start an AsyncTask with all the thumbnail URLs and call that in onProgressUpdate. Not sure where you'd store the thumbnails though.